# Why won't expo-updates provide checkForUpdateAsync?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

When I transitioned to Expo's Managed Workflow (SDK 37 and now 38 as well), in-app update checking broke.

My code:

```
import * as Updates from 'expo-updates';

async checkForUpdate() {
    const update = await Updates.checkForUpdateAsync();
    if (update.isAvailable) {
        this.updateApp();
    }
}
async updateApp() {
    await Updates.fetchUpdateAsync();
    Updates.reloadAsync();
}
```

Logcat shows me that the checkForUpdateAsync() promise is being rejected with this message:

`Error: The method or property Updates.checkForUpdateAsync is not available on android, are you sure you’ve linked all the native dependencies properly?`

For the record I did install it via `expo install expo-updates`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a new Expo project and looking for differences from my many-times-upgraded one.  I found two:

- I was using off-the-shelf React Native instead of the Expo build, so I changed the dependency in `package.json` to `"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.1.tar.gz"`
- I also updated my expo version to `^38.0.8`, as used by the new project.

Finally, I also deleted some build relics that I had generated during the way, but I think the fix came from one of the steps above.